# path based routing with springdoc openapi 3

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

We have path based routing set up for one of our applications as follows

```
https://api.example.com/mailservice
```

It is at this endpoint that api's are able to call the MailService application. However, i am unable to see the swagger-ui page load when i navigate to it from this endpoint:

```
https://api.example.com/mailservice/swagger-ui/index.html
```

But i get the following page:
[image]

Not sure if there's something im missing, some assistance on this would be helpful!

Comment: Please share the Spring Boot & Springdoc version you're using and any related configuration that you have.

Comment: Have you checked browser console on network tab? 
It must be a get request to location like http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs/swagger-config which might shed more light on the issue. 

And +1 to @DebarghaRoy for configs sharing.